# SQL Server UPDATE Command Fails without error

Tags: sql-server, update

Using SSMS running the below UPDATE command I get returned message says 1 row affected. but if I then follow it up with a Select and it shows that the row never updated.

This issue happens in SSMS and a custom application I built in C# using Entity Framework. I have since stopped using Entity Framework generated code and moved straight to a stored proc. All of 3 different ways of performing the same task I randomly get this issue. Sometimes it can be 100's or 1000's of updates before the issue happens again or it could be a few updates later it happens again.
I have run UPDATE STATISTICS, I have Rebuilt Indexes and Reorganized Indexes.

As a side note, I NEVER have an issue with INSERTs only UPDATEs we never DELETE any records. and total record count on the table is 201,741

```
UPDATE CreativeWorkFlowQueue
    SET CurrentIndicator = 'N'
WHERE CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = 198231

SELECT *
FROM CreativeWorkFlowQueue
WHERE CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = 198231
```

[image]

here is the table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue](
    [CreativeWorkFlowQueueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DigitalCampaignCreativeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WorkFlowQueueId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CurrentIndicator] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CreativeWorkFlowQueueId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [CreateDate defaults to utcDate on CreativeWorkFlowQueue]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [LastUpdatedDate defaults to utcDate on CreativeWorkFlowQueue]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [LastUpdatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_CreativeWorkFlowQueue_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue DigitalCampaignCreativeId fk] FOREIGN KEY([DigitalCampaignCreativeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DigitalCampaignCreative] ([DigitalCampaignCreativeId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue DigitalCampaignCreativeId fk]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue WorkFlowQueueId fk] FOREIGN KEY([WorkFlowQueueId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[WorkFlowQueue] ([WorkFlowQueueId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CreativeWorkFlowQueue] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CreativeWorkFlowQueue WorkFlowQueueId fk]
GO
```

**EDIT Adding the Stored Proc that also has the same issue.**

I did not include this stored proc simply due to the fact that it is complex and if a simple update doesn't work I figured start there first.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WtvToRtl] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @tbl DCCIdList READONLY,    
    @WorkFlowQueueId int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    
    DECLARE @dccList TABLE (
        CreativeWorkflowQueueId int null,
        DigitalCampaignCreativeId int null,
        WorkFlowQueueId int null,
        CurrentIndicator varchar(1) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS null,
        LastUpdatedDate datetime null
    )

    DECLARE @DCIDList TABLE(
        DigitalCampaignCreativeId int null
    )





        DECLARE @res TABLE (
        MergeAction VARCHAR(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ,
        CreativeWorkFlowQueueId INT, 
        _Position INT
        )

    BEGIN TRANSACTION t1

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO @dccList (CreativeWorkflowQueueId, DigitalCampaignCreativeId,LastUpdatedDate,WorkFlowQueueId,CurrentIndicator)
        select CreativeWorkflowQueueId, DigitalCampaignCreativeId,LastUpdatedDate,WorkFlowQueueId, 'N' as CurrentIndicator from 
        dbo.CreativeWorkFlowQueue Where CurrentIndicator = 'Y' 
        and IsDeleted = 0
        and DigitalCampaignCreativeId In 
        (SELECT DigitalCampaignCreativeId FROM VRF.DigitalCampaignCreative 
        WHERE IsDeleted = 0 and SfClosed = 0 
        and DccId in (Select DccId COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS from @tbl)
        )
         
         INSERT INTO @DCIDList 
         SELECT DigitalCampaignCreativeId FROM @dccList
         GROUP BY DigitalCampaignCreativeId

        INSERT INTO @dccList (DigitalCampaignCreativeId,WorkFlowQueueId,CurrentIndicator)
        select DigitalCampaignCreativeId, @WorkFlowQueueId as WorkFlowQueueId, 'Y' as CurrentIndicator from 
        @DCIDList


        MERGE vrf.CreativeWorkFlowQueue a
        USING 
            (
            SELECT 
                x.CreativeWorkflowQueueId,
                x.DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
                x.LastUpdatedDate,
                x.WorkFlowQueueId,
                x.CurrentIndicator 
            FROM @dccList x
            ) stg  
    
        ON stg.CreativeWorkflowQueueId = a.CreativeWorkflowQueueId

        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                a.CurrentIndicator  = stg.CurrentIndicator,
                a.LastUpdatedDate = getutcdate()
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT 
                (
                    CurrentIndicator,
                    DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
                    WorkFlowQueueId
                )
            VALUES 
                (
                    stg.CurrentIndicator, 
                    stg.DigitalCampaignCreativeId, 
                    stg.WorkFlowQueueId
                )  
            -- ********************************************************************
            -- Remove this if you don't need to return the results below.
            OUTPUT 
                INSERTED.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId,
                $action 
            INTO @res (CreativeWorkFlowQueueId, MergeAction);
            -- ********************************************************************


        COMMIT TRANSACTION t1

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;
        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS NVARCHAR(5)), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
        --RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
        SELECT 'FAILED' MergeAction,
                s.CreativeWorkflowQueueId,
                s.DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
                '' DccId,
                s.WorkFlowQueueId,
                s.CurrentIndicator,
                null CreateDate,
                null LastUpdatedDate,
                null IsDeleted,
                @ErrorMessage ErrorMessage
        FROM @dccList s
    END CATCH


    -- Normally, I would not have this.  But this will simulate
    -- what EF does if you need it.
    SELECT 
        r.MergeAction,
        a.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId,
        a.DigitalCampaignCreativeId,
        d.DccId,
        a.WorkFlowQueueId,
        a.CurrentIndicator,
        a.CreateDate, 
        a.LastUpdatedDate,
        a.IsDeleted,
        '' ErrorMessage
    FROM vrf.CreativeWorkFlowQueue a 
    JOIN @res r ON a.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId = r.CreativeWorkFlowQueueId
    JOIN vrf.DigitalCampaignCreative d ON a.DigitalCampaignCreativeId = d.DigitalCampaignCreativeId
    ORDER BY 
        r.MergeAction,
        r._Position


END
```

The User-Defined Table Type is this.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DCCIdList] AS TABLE(
    [DccId] [nvarchar](18) NULL
)
```

There are no triggers defined on the table.  Also, in attempting to diagnose if this is an issue with `MERGE`, I ran a simple basic update command, with the same result.  If I run it enough times it will eventually update.

Comment: When you run a [DBCC USEROPTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-useroptions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) what is the isolation level of that database?

Comment: Can you check if that happens for: 1. Any other table in the same database? 2. Any table in a different database on the same SQL instance? 3. Any other user from a different? Also, see if the [OUTPUT](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-update-statements) clause is any help.

Comment: Any error messages in the sql error log ?

Comment: If you check for corruption with DBCC CHECKDB does it come back clean ?